# How to create sequelize ORM for certain SQL statement

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

There is a project for to me create data list by sequelize ORM

and there is a demand for me to construct certain SQL statement showed as below

```
SELECT 
  OrderInfo.tel, 
  OrderInfo.mobile, 
  OrderInfo.order_sn, 
  OrderInfo.order_id, 
  PickupDeliveryOrderRemark.remark, 
  PickupStore.region AS PickupStore.region, 
  PickupStore.district AS PickupStore.district, 
  PickupStore.area AS PickupStore.area, 
  PickupStore.shop_name AS PickupStore.shop_name, 
  PickupStore.address AS PickupStore.address, 
  PickupStore.latitude AS PickupStore.latitude, 
  PickupStore.longitude AS PickupStore.longitude, 
  PickupStore.business_working_day AS PickupStore.business_working_day, 
  PickupStore.business_holiday AS PickupStore.business_holiday, 
  PickupStore.code AS PickupStore.code, 
  IFNULL(MassDelivery.mass_key, '/') AS mass_key, 
  DeliveryOrder.invoice_no 
FROM 
  ecs_order_info AS OrderInfo 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pickup_store AS PickupStore ON OrderInfo.pickup_pt_code collate utf8_general_ci = PickupStore.code 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pickup_delivery_order_remark AS PickupDeliveryOrderRemark ON OrderInfo.order_id = PickupDeliveryOrderRemark.order_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_mass_delivery AS MassDelivery ON OrderInfo.order_id = MassDelivery.order_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_delivery_order AS DeliveryOrder ON OrderInfo.order_id = DeliveryOrder.order_id 
WHERE 
  (
    OrderInfo.shipping_id = 19 
    AND OrderInfo.pay_status = 2 
    AND (
      DeliveryOrder.pickup_status NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4) 
      OR DeliveryOrder.pickup_status IS NULL
    )
  );
```

I don't know how to construct the effect of `[ON OrderInfo.pickup_pt_code collate utf8_general_ci = PickupStore.code]` just by sequelize ORM

I want to construct the SQL statement showed above by sequelize ORM only

Answer (score 0):

First you need define the required models. Then construct the query by using sequelize orm.

Here is an example model:

```js
const OrderInfo = sequelize.define('OrderInfo', {
  tel: DataTypes.STRING,
  mobile: DataTypes.STRING,
  order_sn: DataTypes.STRING,
  order_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  shipping_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  pay_status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  ...
});

const PickupStore = sequelize.define('PickupStore', {
  region: DataTypes.STRING,
  district: DataTypes.STRING,
  area: DataTypes.STRING,
  ...
});

const MassDelivery = sequelize.define('MassDelivery', {
  mass_key: DataTypes.STRING,
  ...
});
```

Continue for DeliveryOrder, PickupDeliveryOrderRemark etc.

Then declare relationship for models.

Example :

```js
OrderInfo.belongsTo(PickupStore, { foreignKey: 'pickup_pt_code', targetKey: 'code' });
OrderInfo.hasOne(MassDelivery, { foreignKey: 'order_id' });
...
```

You need to define all relationship across models. For more info [read documents](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/).

Finally, construct the query. [Read model querying basics.](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics)

Comment: but I cannot still construct the content of [ON OrderInfo.pickup_pt_code collate utf8_general_ci = PickupStore.code] in sql statement by this method,this is the key point of this question.